# How to bend a specific part of an object or differently achieve a bend/round surface

Tags: modeling, modifiers

this is actually my first post on the Blender StackExchange so I hope I ask my question properly^^.

I am rather new to Blender and currently trying to model a Desert Eagle. It's going good so far, just started it 2 hours ago but now I ran into a problem. I am trying to make the red marked piece of the gun but I have actually no Idea how to properly get this bend surface. I thought about using a Deform Modifier, but as the whole green marked part is one object it would bend the whole object, which I obviously don't want. Sculpting isnt really an option for me as I want to keep it as low poly as possible additionally I have no clue how sculpting works, actually never used it. Is there any option to get it close to the picture? I doesn't have to be perfectly round but I cannot manage to even get close to a rounded surface.

Thanks to all of you in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your base shape is a cylinder you could begin with a cylinder and use the *Boolean* modifier to cut off the parts you're talking about, then continue to model, create some edge loops, use the knife, and at the end add some bevels to sharp the edges:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I dont know what is going on now, I tried your suggestion. But when I want to test the boolean, the object that should get cut out gets applied to it instead. So I have basically a "copy" of the mesh I made to cut it out attached to my barrel mesh.

Comment: you need to give a Boolean to the cylinder, and make sure that the mode is Difference

Comment: Yeah, I did,i used booleans before and never had this. The boolean is applied to the object I want to make the cut in and is set to difference.

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Yeah, will do now, i actually hard shaped the barrel again, with a cube this time and it still happens...

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=LQAsgxNE" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/LQAsgxNE/) Here, this is the file TestBarrel is the one I just made for testing, Barrel is the original one the should be cut.

Comment: you need to remove some doubles: select the cutting object, go in Edit mode and press alt M (Merge) > By Distance, otherwise the Boolean bugs

Comment: Same is still happening, Cylinder is my original barrel, mixed it up as I remade it. And i  removed all doubles from both cutter/cutted still doesnt work. Works with the new test barrel now tho

Comment: I don't know what happens, it works on the file you've sent me

Comment: I guess I use my test barrel then and remodel it then. But last problem now is that I cannot show my modifier in edit mode. The button for this just in there in the boolean modifier tab